# How to use plugin dependencies in MANIFEST.MF from workspace and not target platform?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, dependencies, manifest

I need to add a plugin dependency into my plugin from the wokrspace. Lets say this to be added plugins name is "X". X is first in my target platform installed as a plugin, and I imported it into my workspace to make some major changes. After I am done, I needed to add this into another plugin as a dependancy to be able use the new improvements. But, in MANIFEST it is always being accessed from the target platform, meaning the old plugin installed in my plugin directory is being added as dependency.

I know there is the difference between plugin icons in manifet. If there is an arrow it is added from the target platform and a circle from the workspace etc. In the above case I have an icon with "01" by this X's dependency. And I need to add it from my workspace.

Is this possible? I couldn't find any options to change the location of a plugin being add as a dependency. Is this even possible, or do we let Eclipse choose it?

Thanks!

Comment: You could try changing the plugin version and specifying the required min / max version in the dependency property.

Comment: Well, they both have the same plugin version. I have never thought of changing the improved plugins version. Would it break any functions?

Comment: If the plugin is marked as a singleton and the version still falls withing any range expected by the other plugins using it then this should be OK.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work. But I had my workaround by this with simply deleting the project from the development environment and just keeping the plugins projects with the source code in my workspace. But do you have any better ideas?